# Configuring Atom for running Python

Tags: python, configuration, atom

I have been trying to setup Atom editor for running python programs on Ubuntu 18
The packages I installed are : 
script 
atom-runner 
autocomplete-python 
python-tools

I even configured the config.cson file as per the atom-runner configuration .

I am getting the following error:

Atom Runner: testing.py
Atom Runner: testing.py

Unable to find command: python
Are you sure PATH is configured correctly?

is there something else I need to do ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It just needed to install Python on system. Make sure you have installed it well before.

To install it :

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/07/install-python-3-6-1-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts/

Comment: Phython is preinstalled on Ubuntu. Please describe in more detail what you have installed and which commands  you used.

Comment: No it wasnt . Atleast not in mine  . I was getting this error and all I had to do was install Python . To install it :   http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/07/install-python-3-6-1-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts/

Answer (score 0):

There is a section about this error in the FAQs for the atom-runner package [here](https://atom.io/packages/atom-runner) that may help you.

It would seem that the python command is not in your path. Check where python is in your system with

```
which python
```

and check that the path (or at least part of it) is in your PATH:

```
echo $PATH
```

If not, adding the path to python to your PATH should solve the problem. To do so, add the following line to your `.bashrc` file:

```
export PATH=$PATH:[your path to python here]
```

replace the square bracket with the output from `which python`